# wrappedComponentRef is undefined - React Ant Design, Form Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I am using Ant design - Form and Modal components with React.

Form wrapper component:

```
class InsertForm extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const formItemLayout = {
            labelCol: { span: 24 },
            wrapperCol: { span: 24},
        };
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        return (
            <div>
                <Form.Item
                    {...formItemLayout}
                    label="Title"
                >
                    {getFieldDecorator('title', {

                    })(
                        <Input placeholder="Title" />
                    )}
                 </Form.Item>
......
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const InsertFormWrapper = Form.create()(InsertForm);
```

I am calling this component in another component in the same file (that's why I am not exporting the form component) inside a `Modal` and I am using `wrappedComponentRef`:

```
export default class InsertCont extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log(this.form) // Undefined
    }
    insert = () => {
            console.log(this.form); // Not undefined
        }
    render(){
        <Modal
            ...{modalProps}
            onOk={this.insert}
        >
            <InsertFormWrapper
                wrappedComponentRef={(form) => this.form = form}
            />
        </Modal>
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the constructor the ref `this.form` is undefined, but if the modal is open and OK button is clicked - `onOk={this.insert}`  the ref is not undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's undefined in the constructor is that when you get to the constructor, your code has only defined `InsertCont`, but has not yet called `render()`, which is where the `wrappedComponentRef` sets `this.form`

Please refer to [The React Lifecycle: Mounting](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting) to see why this is so.  When any React component is created, this is the order that functions are called:

1. `constructor()`
2. `static getDerivedStateFromProps()`
3. `render()`
4. `componentDidMount()`

Answer (score 1):

BTW I have not fully looked at your problem or code but I had the same problem and solved it so I think I know what's wrong.

You cannot pass components with wrappers into other components. I think it has to be its own route (in `BrowserRouter`).

Meaning the problem is in the wrapper component... here ->

```
const InsertFormWrapper = Form.create()(InsertForm);
```

then using it in the render of `InsertCont` component... here ->

```
render() {
        <InsertFormWrapper
            wrappedComponentRef={(form) => this.form = form}
        />
    </Modal>
}
```

You have a couple solutions

- remove the wrapper and find another way to implement what you need
- make the component its own route somehow
- dash the whole component in the bin

Choose wisely ;)